# Validar si hay datos en el formulario sin guardar, antes de cambiar de vista

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular8

Quiero realizar una validación de cuando hayan datos en el formulario y me vaya a salir de esa vista sin haber guardado los datos arroje una alerta de que hay datos sin guardar, un ejemplo de esto seria lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Al recargar la pagina o intentar ir a otro menú de la aplicación genera este aviso**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero lograr esto mismo que sugerencias me podrían dar para lograr esto. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con la funcion `window.onbeforeunload`

```
<script>
     window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        alert("esta apunto de salir")
    }
</script>
```

Puedes leer mas sobre su uso [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

podrías preguntar si posee datos y posteriormente  preguntar si quiere salir o no:

```js
import {
  FormControl
} from '@angular/forms';


export class Test {

  dataInput = new FormControl('');

  closing() {
    if (this.isInputWithData) {
      //Aqui puedes insertar la salida, ya que confirma que quiere descartar
      //window.close() por ejemplo para cerrar la ventana
    }
  }

  isInputWithData(): boolean {
    if (this.dataInput.value != '' || this.dataInput.dirty) { //cualquiera de las 2 te sirve
      return confirm(' Discard changes?'); // si hubiese datos te pregunta
      //Esto traerá true o false dependiendo de tu elección
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" [formControl]="dataInput">
</form>
```

Espero que te sirva !

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr esto con angular solo requieres lo siguiente:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
  unloadHandler(event) {
    // ...
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', [ '$event' ])
  beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Suponiendo que utilices reactives forms puedes utilizar `this.tuFormulario.touched || this.tuFormulario.dirty`. Aunque yo solo usaria `dirty`

Puedes ver [esta respuesta en ingles aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37642657/4326551)